# Remote control for LG UltraFine Ergo 4K IPS monitor?

Tags: monitors, remote-control

I purchased an [LG UltraFine Ergo 4K IPS monitor](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-32un880-b-4k-uhd-led-monitor) (ID: 32UN880-B.BEU).
Is there a way to use a remote control with it?
(The goal is to change monitor settings from the remote)

Comment: How often do you need to change the settings ?

Comment: Often, I'm using the monitor for work but also as a TV replacement

Comment: What monitor settings do you need to change specifically? If it's things that are controllable via DDC/CI, such as input/brightness/contrast, it's probably doable; if it's more complex things such as color space or aspect ratio, almost certainly not.